# Anything you want to salvage from Lit.SE?

Tags: discussion

[Literature.SE, along with some other betas, is being closed in a week](https://literature.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/349/literature-is-closing).

[Other sites are salvaging these sites via migration](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/130342/178438)

Now, I'm not a regular member of either Lit.SE or Writers.SE, but it did occur to me that you guys have some topical overlap.

Please check out the Lit.SE questions and flag the relevant ones for migration to Writers. If you want a wholesale tag migrate, please list it here (or comment on the mother meta post)

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Composing a quick list:

- https://literature.stackexchange.com/questions/624/what-exactly-is-conceptual-writing
- https://literature.stackexchange.com/questions/234/what-effect-on-literature-has-the-introduction-of-ebooks-and-ereaders-had
- https://literature.stackexchange.com/questions/1008/rhetoric-vs-figure-of-speech
- https://literature.stackexchange.com/questions/1000/how-do-limited-edition-book-pre-orders-work
- https://literature.stackexchange.com/questions/822/notes-placement
- https://literature.stackexchange.com/questions/338/how-much-influence-do-authors-have-on-their-titles
- https://literature.stackexchange.com/questions/1096/source-for-literary-terms
- https://literature.stackexchange.com/questions/1504/literary-criticism-term-for-character-espousing-authors-ideas

I found these mostly by scanning the taglist for things that looked relevant, and searching for "writing."

Haven't flagged these yet; anybody got any objections to any of these?

Comment: Being a mod, I think you're qualified to know on-topicness on this site, so i'd just flag if I were you. Leave a note in there that you're a W.SE mod, otherwise they'll go through the whole process of asking a mod of this site about topicity. Spare 'em the trouble :)

Answer (score 2):

Standback hit all of the questions we had identified in chat except this one, I believe:

### [American authors paid by word/page?](https://literature.stackexchange.com/questions/946/american-authors-paid-by-word-page)

> I buy quite a lot of literature, mostly of academic nature. One thing I have noticed is that books by American authors always tend to be more explicit and contain more examples, regarding whatever subject.  Now, I have heard a rumor that American authors get paid by the word/page; hence the massive size of the books. Is this true?

Comment: I'm not crazy about the question as appropriate to us, but the answer is nice.

Answer (score 2):

In answer to Standback's list of questions, here's my opinion on whether they're suitable here. For a question to work on Writers, it has to be about writing, writers, or, in some way, the making of books.

[What exactly is “Conceptual Writing?”](https://literature.stackexchange.com/questions/624/what-exactly-is-conceptual-writing) - This question is vague. If it were asked, we'd edit it to be more about *Writing* or close it. And it's more a philosophical question than one about writing.

[What effect on literature has the introduction of eBooks and eReaders had?](https://literature.stackexchange.com/questions/234/what-effect-on-literature-has-the-introduction-of-ebooks-and-ereaders-had) I really, really want to have a question like this here. But it is about reading, not writing.

[Rhetoric vs Figure of Speech](https://literature.stackexchange.com/questions/1008/rhetoric-vs-figure-of-speech) - Sure, bring this one on in. It's about the mechanics of techniques for writing.

[How do limited edition book pre-orders work?](https://literature.stackexchange.com/questions/1000/how-do-limited-edition-book-pre-orders-work) I'm on the fence about this one. Sure, let's bring it on it!

[Notes placement](https://literature.stackexchange.com/questions/822/notes-placement) - Bring it!

[How much influence do authors have on their titles?](https://literature.stackexchange.com/questions/338/how-much-influence-do-authors-have-on-their-titles) could use some better answers, but the question is clearly on-topic here. Bring it!

[Source for literary terms?](https://literature.stackexchange.com/questions/1096/source-for-literary-terms) Off-topic here, it's about reading, not writing.

[Literary criticism term for character espousing author's ideas?](https://literature.stackexchange.com/questions/1504/literary-criticism-term-for-character-espousing-authors-ideas) This is a writing technique, even though it's from the POV of the reader. Bring it!

Comment: Of course, there will be editing. Anyway, lots of posts are tailored to the new site after migration :)

Comment: IMHO literary terminology can be on topic since writers are (well, can be) very aware of it in their writing. e.g. the "mouthpiece" question is a particular example of where the "source for literary terms" might be helpful. Also, I think pretty much anything about the publishing industry is **firmly** on-topic here.

Comment: Looks like a couple of these did get flagged by Standback for migration and I'm afraid I didn't check back here until after migrating them just now.  Feel free to close any of them that aren't appropriate, of course.